# Is it possible to set the reporter field in Bugzilla when creating a bug?

Tags: bugzilla

Scenario:

I get a mail from `Foo Bar` about a problem. I add the issue to Bugzilla and would like `Foo Bar` to be the reporter of the issue so it will be possible to do searches on issues reported by this individual etc.

I understand that I most likley will have to create dummy users for every reporting person since Bugzilla only works with the users in it's system. But if I could live with that, would it be possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it would be to actually log in as the dummy user when reporting the bug.  (Or if you have permission, use the impersonation feature.)

To make the reporter field editable on the bug submission form, you'd have to edit the source code.

The impersonation feature is documented [here](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/useradmin.html#impersonatingusers).  Quoting briefly:

> You may start a session by going to
>   the Edit Users page, Searching for a
>   user and clicking on their login. You
>   should see a link below their login
>   name titled "Impersonate this user".
>   Click on the link. This will take you
>   to a page where you will see a
>   description of the feature and
>   instructions for using it. After
>   reading the text, simply enter the
>   login of the user you would like to
>   impersonate, provide a short message
>   explaining why you are doing this, and
>   press the button.

Comment: All of these are feasible but I think the inpersonation feature is what I'm looking for.

Comment: How do I impersonate a user when creating a bug? I can't seem to create as any other user than myself, and I'm a have the privilege "bz_sudoers:  Can perform actions as other users"

Comment: Nice. Would have been a bit more user friendly if you could just get a drop down when creating a bug and select the reporter where your name currently shows up. Thanx though m8

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in the web interface to do this.

It can be achieved via the XMLRPC mehtod only, but this is not suitable for most use cases:

```
bugzilla.changeAssignment($bugid, { reporter => new@reporter.com },
$username, $password);
```

Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=432238